# place custom view in a relative layout with a drawable background android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I'm having a problem with creating my layout in android. The problem is that I have a relative layout with a image as a background. Inside of the relative layout is a view that has an opacity (alpha) of 0.5. In android studio the layout looks fine and the elements inside of the relative layout are on top of the view. However when i run the application the view with the black background isnt there ,just the image.
Below is the xml layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/login_relLayout"
android:background="@drawable/mainImage">

<View
    android:id="@+id/customView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/login_relLayout"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:alpha="0.8" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Testing"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/customView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
android:id="@+id/emailTextInput"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="47dp"
    android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    >

<EditText
android:layout_width="320dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_person"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
android:id="@+id/email"
android:hint="@string/email"
 />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/passwordTextInput"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/emailTextInput"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/emailTextInput"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/emailTextInput"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/emailTextInput"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/emailTextInput"
    android:textColorHint="#ffffff"
    android:textColor="#ffffff">

      <EditText
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_lock"
        android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_visibility"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_visibility"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:hint="@string/password"
        android:imeOptions="actionGo"
        />
  </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>



  <LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_below="@id/passwordTextInput"
   android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
   android:layout_alignRight="@+id/passwordTextInput"
   android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/passwordTextInput"
   android:weightSum="1"
   android:id="@+id/linLayout"
   android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/passwordTextInput"
   android:layout_alignStart="@+id/passwordTextInput">

   <Button
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="@string/signIn"
       android:id="@+id/signIn"
       android:layout_weight="0.5"
       android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
       android:layout_below="@+id/passwordTextInput"
       android:background="@drawable/transaprent_button"
       android:textColor="#ffffff" />

   <Button
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="Sign up"
       android:layout_weight="0.5"
       android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
       android:background="@drawable/transaprent_button"
       android:textColor="#ffffff"
       android:id="@+id/signUp"

        />

 </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: what is size of the mainimage. resolution and kb ?

Comment: Maybe you could add screenshots? From preview in AS and your Phone?

Comment: What's the API level of your devide? The minimum API level for "alpha" property is 11